# Custom Action changing InstallPrivileges

Tags: wix, windows-installer, elevated-privileges

I am writing a .wxs file that has at the top

```
<Product Id="*" Name="My Fancy Product" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="My Company, Inc." UpgradeCode="AAA79BAB-B246-4326-B875-024022F393C6">
    <Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="limited" InstallScope="perUser" />
```

I need to change `InstallPrivileges`from `limited`to `elevated`, depending on certain conditions.  (I also need to do something similar for `InstallScope`).

I wrote a C# custom action:

```
    public static ActionResult SetElevated(Session session)
    {
        // Change InstallPrivileges to "elevated"
        session.Log($"Privileged = {session["Privileged"]}");
        session["Privileged"] = "1";
        session.Log($"{session["Privileged"]}");  // prints "1"

        session.Log($"ALLUSERS = {session["ALLUSERS"]}");
        session["ALLUSERS"] = "1";
        session.Log($"{session["ALLUSERS"]}");    // prints "1"

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

The Custom Action is scheduled:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="SetElevatedCustomAction" Before="MyWelcomeDlg"></Custom>
  ...
</InstallUISequence>

<CustomAction Id="SetElevatedCustomAction" BinaryKey="SetupCustomActionBinary" DllEntry="SetElevated" Execute="immediate" Return="check"  />
```

But the installer does not give the UAC prompt.

I used `Orca` to export all the tables in the compiled MSI and compared it to an MSI generated with `InstallPrivileges="elevated"`, and the only difference was the `ALLUSERS` property, which I set to the same value in the Custom Action.

My guess is `ALLUSERS` can't be changed from a custom action?  How to accomplish a change dynamically then?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling the custom action to be executed as early as possible fixed it:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="SetElevatedCustomAction" Before="LaunchConditions"></Custom>
  ...
</InstallUISequence>
```